# Google 2FA (Two Factor Authentication) installation works with Ubuntu 16.04 Unity Sudo but NOT Login

Tags: authentication, google, pam

I successfully followed the instructions on the linux.com site to setup 2FA on Ubuntu 16.04 Unity. Sudo asks for password then verification code and works. N.B. only accepts correct synced code - so I know the setup works. The problem is that it then locks me out of the login screen when unlocking my LUKS Home drive from fresh boot. It asks for my password as normal - but then tells me it's wrong! If I remove nullok option from the /etc/pam.d/common-auth using a Live CD of Ubuntu it will allow me to log in again. How do I get the graphical interface to work too ?

[Instructions on installing two factor Authentication using Google's Authenticator Android App](https://www.linux.com/learn/how-set-2-factor-authentication-login-and-sudo)

Thanks in advance for any help